# Got an segment error and not sure what causes it

Tags: c, linux

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main () {
    int vIn_a, vIn_b, vIn_c;
    char vOperator;

    
    printf("Please enter a number\n");
    scanf("%d", vIn_a); 
    printf("Please enter a number\n");
    scanf("%d", vIn_b);
    printf("Please enter a Operator\n");
    scanf("%c", vOperator);

    switch(vOperator){
        case '+':
            vIn_c = (vIn_a + vIn_b); 
            break;
        case '-':
            vIn_c = (vIn_a - vIn_b);
            break;
        case '/':
            vIn_c = (vIn_a / vIn_b);
            break;
        case '*':
            vIn_c = (vIn_a * vIn_b);
            break;
    }
    printf("Result: %d %c %d = %d", vIn_a, vOperator, vIn_b, vIn_c);
    return 0;
}
```

Just trying to figure this out, i ran gdb. But not sure what my debugger is telling me at this point. Maybe im overlooking it?
Debugger: **Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7c60d36 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6**

So what is causing this segmentation fault guys? Im learning C and im lost.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Compile the code with debugging symbols. Run it in `gdb`. When it fails, execute the `bt` command. The `bt` command will show you the effect. The root cause might be immediate (your topmost caller in the stack) or it could be some else leading up to the immediate effect.

Comment: You are passing arguments of the wrong type to `scanf`. It needs the addresses of the variables, i.e. `&vIn_a`, `&vIn_b` and `&vOperator`. You will also need to change the `"%c"` in the `scanf` call to `" %c"` so that it can eat up any whitespace before the operator character. Also, you should initialize or assign `vIn_c` before using it - it is possible that none of the `case` labels will be reached, in which case `vIn_c` never gets a value.

Comment: @JeffHolt No, the first step is to enable warnings in the compiler.

Comment: @IanAbbott That worked like a charm. Is that a regular thing to reverse some whitespace for a character?

Comment: @JeffHolt That gave me 3 lines #0  0x00007ffff7c60d36 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7c5bcc2 in __isoc99_scanf () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000555555555189 in main ()

Comment: @P_kidz Yes, most of the `scanf` specifiers skip initial whitespace except for `%c` and `%[` which do not skip initial whitespace. Normally, the previous inputs would be terminated by a newline, which is a whitespace character, and you want to skip it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `scanf()`, you don't pass the variable into which you want to store the value, you pass a **pointer** to the variable.

So, for instance, instead of `scanf("%d", vIn_a);`, you need `scanf("%d", &vIn_a);` - note the '`&`'!

The effect of the `scanf()` calls, as you wrote them, was to pass an arbitrary number (whatever random content was in the uninitialised `vIn_a` and `vIn_b`) into `scanf()`. It treated those random(ish) integer values as pointers. So when it wrote the user-contributed value into the "pointer" it has been passed, it had the effect of:

`*(int *)vIn_a = user_entered_value;`

If you know your way around pointers, you'll know this is a recipe for disaster!

There are two more gotchas:

1. Your '`/`' operator doesn't check whether its divisor (`vIn_b`) is zero, so it would be easy to crash with a divide-by-zero error if the user selected zero for `vIn_b` and '`/`' for the operator.
2. You don't have a `default:` clause in your `switch` statement, so if the user types something other than the operator characters you're checking for, `vIn_c` will contain random rubbish as it's uninitialised by the time it's printed.

Comment: Somehow this made a lot of sense! Thanks for the detailed explanation. Most examples I've read didn't mention the "&" symbol neither. I still need to get used to pointers in this context as well. Back to the documentation for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can use scanf function with &. For example; `scanf("%d", &vIn_a);`

For documentation : https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/